# More elegant approach regarding the camera

Tags: java, camera, coordinates, libgdx

I'm using Libgdx to draw a 2d scene. Before drawing I do this:

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

As expected, the (0,0) coordinates are no longer in the bottom left of the screen, but now at the middle of the screen.

What would be more elegant solution to position the whole scene correctly:

1) Translate/position the camera accordingly to show everything that's on the screen.

2) Draw everything while having in mind that the (0,0) is at the middle now, like so:

```
batch.draw(background, -background.getRegionWidth()/2, -background.getRegionHeight()/2);
```

Note that I'm actually doing [Parallax scrolling](http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/ParallaxTest.java) and the first option dispositions my midground layer objects a bit, as expected. So if there is no good solution to this problem, then I'm leaning more towards the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep your objects in "world space" and keep all the translations from "world space" to the screen in the "camera" (the "camera" is just an abstraction around the matrices that are *defined* to translate world space to screen space).  Polluting your object's locations with information about the screen will cause confusion and problems.

Specifically, in your case, just call

```
camera.translate(width/2, height/2, 0);
```

to get (0, 0) back into the lower left (if your "world space" is entirely in the positive coordinate space.

For more details, search around Stack Overflow for OpenGL camera questions like this: [In 3d graphics, what is camera or eye space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965950/in-3d-graphics-what-is-camera-or-eye-space)